# Finding the most recurring element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am working on a solution to find the smallest common multiple given a range of numbers [1, 13];
So far I have managed to get an array of the range:-
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13] 
and an array of the prime factors for every number in the range: -
[[2],[3],[2,2],[5],[2,3],[7],[2,2,2],[3,3],[5,2],[2,2,3],[13]]

What I want to do is be able to reduce the factors array to the an array containing the most instances of a factor like this:- [[2,2,2], [3,3], [5], [7], [11], [13]]

Is there any way this can be achieved I have been stuck at this point for a while

Comment: Please post a few more details about your environment, e.g. the exact data structures you're using, possibly with a snippet of your code. Otherwise, it's just a mathematical/theoretical CS question and does not fall within the scope of SO.

Comment: what do you do with `[2, 3]` or `[2, 2, 3]`?

Comment: Those will not be recquired, its a method of finding the smallest common multiple, it should be Euclidean; basically all the 2's will be represented by the array with most 2's

Answer (score 0):

Use an array as key/value pair. your key could be a "stringyfied" representation of the factors array, while the value is, of course, {number of occurrences , factor array}. scan the array and increment the corrisponding occurrences. Find the maximum of the occurrence array

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem can divided into

- Integer factorization `getFactors()`
- Count of factors
- Getting only the counts with the higher amount
- Convert the result to an array

```js
function range(a, b) {

    function getFactors(n) {
        var f, count = {};
        while (n !== 1) {
            f = 2;
            while (n % f) { f++; }
            count[f] = (count[f] || 0) + 1;
            n /= f;
        }
        return count;
    }

    var array = [],
        count = {},
        i;

    for (i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        array.push(getFactors(i));
    }
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
            count[k] = Math.max(count[k] || 0, a[k]);
        });
    });
    return Object.keys(count).map(function (k) {
        var r = [];
        while (count[k]--) {
            r.push(+k);
        }
        return r;
    });
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(range(1, 13), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```